# Transforming list of objects to multiselect values control

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a following objects sent from backend

```
[ {
    id : integer,
    name : string
    secondName : string
  }
]
```

I need to transform it to

```
  transformedObjects = {
        options: {
            id: {name, secondName}
            id: {name, secondName}
        ...
        },
        selected: []
    };
```

So, as you can see I would like to put received value to multiselect control and index values via received id.  You also understand me: `name` should be displayed in multi-select.
How to do it ?

Comment: What is `selected` (as far as your question is concerned)? Is that just an empty array to attach to to `transformedObjects` for later use?

Comment: `id: {name, secondName}` this is not valid JSON?

Comment: @skylize, yes it is

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) to learn more about reducing arrays. Or maybe something like [How reduce works, when to use it](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/reduce-f47a7da511a9) for a less academic approach.

```js
    // sample data so we can run the code
    const objs = [
      {
        id : 105,
        name : 'fluffy',
        secondName : 'fluffykins'
      },
      {
        id : 'id#1527',
        name : 'rabbit',
        secondName : 'rabbithole'
      }
    ]

    // Transform array with a reduce calling a function on each item
    //  `acc` is an accumulator, we keep adding to that object 
    //  each time through the loop and return it so it can be passed
    //  into the next loop, obj is the individual object being 
    //  worked on.

    const options = objs.reduce((acc, obj) => {
      acc[obj.id] = {
        name: obj.name,
        secondName: obj.secondName
      }
      return acc
    }, {})

    // Then we can just tack on the `selected` array. It is possible
    //  to shove this part inside the reduce function, but it will 
    //  just make your code much harder to read with no obvious benefit.
    transformedObjects = {
      options,
      selected: []
    }

    // Display results. We are converting to JSON here, so numbered keys will look like strings.
    document.querySelector('#output').innerText = JSON.stringify(transformedObjects, null, 2)
```

```html
transformedObjects = 
<!-- a preformatted text element to display results in -->
<pre id='output'></pre>
```